# Iterate over an array from backward and change value in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop over an array and change the value of one key depending of the next value.

For exemple if I get a "false" value I want all next values as false.

```php
1: true
2: false
3: true
4: true
```

```php
1: true
2: false
3: false
4: false
```

this is what I've tried:

```php
   /** 
     * @Route("/api/guest/laposte", methods="GET")
     */
    public function getData(): JsonResponse
    {
        $array = [
            1 => "1A00915820380",
            2 => "4P36275770836",
            3 => "1K36275770836",
            4 => "4G11111111110",
        ];

        $httpClient = HttpClient::create(['headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => '*',
            'X-Okapi-Key' => 'key'
        ]]);

        $params = [];

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            $response = $httpClient->request('GET', "https://api.laposte.fr/suivi/v2/idships/$value?lang=fr_FR");
            if ($response->getContent()) {
                $params[$i] = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
            }
            $i++;
        }


        foreach ($params as $timelines) {
            foreach (array_reverse($timelines["shipment"]["timeline"]) as $value) {
                if ($value["status"] == true) {
                    $value["status"] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->json($params);
    }
```

I don't get any erros but it doesn't change any value

Comment: Second, the value is a _copy_, you can not modify that directly inside the loop - unless you use it as a _reference_ (details, see manual on foreach), or you would need to access the original array directly (you also need the key then, so use the extended foreach syntax) to overwrite the value in there.

Comment: (First comment removed, did not see that the second part was two _nested_ foreach loops again.)